# Best Practices for sharing in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

When a user shares a document (say Document1) in SharePoint with another user (say User1), SharePoint will break permission inheritance on that document and create a new security context for that one document with a copy of the parent’s security context and add User1 to the security context with Edit Permissions.

If a user then shares the Document Library that contained the previously mention document with yet another user (User2), then User2 will not have access to Document1, because it has broken inheritance.(I think this is changed in SharePoint Online).

Are there any documented Best Practices on how to deal with this? I’m thinking of telling users that they can share individual documents but not Webs. If they want to ‘share’ a Web, they should add the user to the appropriate security group. In that case the User2 would get permissions to Document1, because when we broke inheritance, it copied the group permissions to the child item.

It gets even more confusing when we include lists and folders in the scenario.

Any suggestions, past experiences or other insights would be appreciated.